# arreglar formato ion.rangeSlider en decimales

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de jalar el resultado de decimales de ion.rangeslider pero me sale 2.3;10 quiero eliminar ese ";10"use split(";10"); pero sale "1%," sale una coma

```
$("#range-slider-5").ionRangeSlider({
        min: 0,
        max: 10,
        step: 0.1,
        type: 'double',
        skin: "big",
        hasGrid: false,
        hideText: false,
    });

    $("#range-slider-5").on("change", function () {
        var $inp = $(this);
        ingreso_nuevo = $inp.prop("value"); // reading input value
        var imprimir =ingreso_nuevo.split(";10");
        document.getElementById('calc_interes').innerHTML = ingreso_nuevo+' %';
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USar Replace es la solucion

```
$("#range-slider-5").on("change", function () {
    var $inp = $(this);
    ingreso_nuevo = $inp.prop("value"); // reading input value
    var imprimir =ingreso_nuevo.replace(";10"," ");
    document.getElementById('calc_interes').innerHTML = imprimir+' %';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba utilizando split(";")[0] para obtener el primer elemento ya que regresa un arreglo.
split(";") por si te llega un valor diferente al ";10" en tu variable ingreso_nuevo

ejemplo:

```
$("#range-slider-5").on("change", function () {
    var $inp = $(this);
    ingreso_nuevo = $inp.prop("value"); // reading input value
    var imprimir =ingreso_nuevo.split(";")[0];
    document.getElementById('calc_interes').innerHTML = imprimir+' %';
});
```